# Передача параметров из контроллера в представление yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Возникла проблема в передачи переменной из контроллера в вид. Использую такой код в контроллере:
Расположение файла - frontend/controllers/SiteController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $my_variable = "My variable";
    return $this->render('index', [
        'my_variable' => $my_variable,
    ]);
}
```

И такой код во view:
Расположение файла - frontend/views/site/index.php

```
<?echo $my_variable;?>
```

Проблема в том что во view переменной $my_variable не существует (об этом говорит PhpStorm, а при загрузке страницы никаких ошибок нет, просто пустая страница. В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: `<?php echo $my_variable; ?>` ?

Comment: Да, так заработало, спасибо.

Comment: не используй асп теги..... используй `<php ... ?>`  для вывода (замена echo) можно `<?= $var; ?>` .......... а вот так `<? ...........  ?>` - не пиши. только боли оберешься

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте интеграцию фреймворка в шторм, и используйте во view нотации Такого вида

```
/** @var $my_variable string */
```